# mui ToggleButtonGroup onChange event as a prop not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I can't get the onChange value when i send it as a prop to be reusable

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
    orientation="vertical"
    value={view}
    exclusive
    onChange={handleFilterClick}
    sx={{
      width: '100%',
      '&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-root .Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0 253 255 / 19%) !important',
      },
    }}
  >
```

and inside the page

```
const handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, nextView: string) => {
setView(nextView);};
```

i have 3 issues

1. the onChange event works without sending args but i can't get the value
2. i can't send event arg, event is deprecated
3. when i add the args i get this error : Type '(event: React.MouseEvent, value: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'VoidFunction'

   <MntHeaderWidget
   CardTitle={RtToggle.CardTitle}
   ToggleValue={RtToggle.ToggleValue}
   headerIcon={RtToggle.headerIcon}
   handleFilterClick={(event: React.MouseEvent, value: string) => handleChange(event, value)}
   data={RtToggle.data}
   />

how should i pass the function ?
example stackblitz from mui (this onchange event is one the same page but i want to send it as a prop) : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/utt8rq--run?file=demo.tsx)